# Get total minutes until tomorrow

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to get the minutes until `00:00:00` (until the day changes) but in Chicago timezone. I set my timezone to chicago (temporarly) then reset it to my original. There thing I am currently struggling with is getting the amount of minutes until the day changes. I need the minutes as I am trying to set a cookie that will expire as soon as it turns tomorrow.

```
$oldTimezone = date_default_timezone_get();
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
// TODO: Get the minutes while Chicago is active.
date_default_timezone_set($oldTimezone);
```

Comment: Don't you set the cookie `expires` property to [_"date-in-GMTString-format"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Syntax)?

Comment: You need to get into the habit of accepting answers. You'll earn good reputation at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
echo (strtotime('tomorrow') - strtotime('now')) / 60;
```

Note: This is not a formatted string, if you wish to format in `H:i:s`, this will work:

```
echo date("H:i:s", (strtotime('tomorrow') - strtotime('now')));
```

Comment: Seems like you fell onto someone who either doesn't know how to mark questions as solved, or doesn't want to bother. I left them [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554764/get-total-minutes-until-tomorrow/48554920#comment84166648_48554764) about it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yeah, that's a problem with new users. I think high rep guys should have this option to mark as resolved. Anyways, even I need to rethink weather I should answer users with low rep as you have in your bio ;)

Comment: Well, it's a per member decision. But that idea of yours isn't a crazy one ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Haha, I understand ;) Btw I wanted to say this, you are a nice man and also Funky guy ;) Nice to talk to you :)

Comment: Thanks Aniket; that's nice of  you to say, *cheers* - same here.

Comment: A "funky guy"? You only know the half of it @AniketSahrawat :-)

Comment: Maybe . . . : )